# Error: Cannot instantiate interface Magento\ReCaptchaWebapiApi\Api\WebapiValidationConfigProviderInterface in /Factory/AbstractFactory.php:121

Tags: checkout, extensions, shipping, shipping-methods, guest-checkout

I have just upgraded my Magento version from **2.4.0 to 2.4.6** and I am getting this error on the **checkout/#shipping** page the shipping methods are not displaying and throwing this error in the network.

```
s/hollywoo/dev/public_html/app/code/Manadev/Core/Helper.php(185): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}()
#18 /hollywoo/dev/public_html/app/code/Manadev/Core/Plugins/RestPlugin.php(20): Manadev\Core\Helper->handleHttpAndLogAllQueries()
```

I know it is because of this **Manadev/Core/Helper.php** code. Providing code for debugging

```
<?php
/** 
 * @copyright   Copyright (c) http://www.manadev.com
 * @license     http://www.manadev.com/license  Proprietary License
 */

namespace Manadev\Core;

use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;
use Manadev\Core\Contracts\PageType;
use Manadev\Core\Registries\PageTypes;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface;

class Helper {
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http
     */
    protected $request;
    /**
     * @var PageTypes
     */
    protected $pageTypes;
    /**
     * @var QueryLogger
     */
    protected $queryLogger;
    /**
     * @var Configuration
     */
    protected $configuration;

    public function __construct(
        RequestInterface $request,
        PageTypes $pageTypes,
        QueryLogger $queryLogger,
        Configuration $configuration
    ) {
        $this->request = $request;
        $this->pageTypes = $pageTypes;
        $this->queryLogger = $queryLogger;
        $this->configuration = $configuration;
    }
    public function getCurrentRoute() {
        return str_replace('_', '/', strtolower($this->request->getFullActionName()));
    }

    /**
     * @param string|null $route
     * @return PageType
     */
    public function getPageType($route = null) {
        return $this->pageTypes->get($route ?: $this->getCurrentRoute());
    }

    public function decodeGridSerializedInput($encoded) {
        $result = array();
        parse_str($encoded, $decoded);
        foreach ($decoded as $key => $value) {
            $result[$key] = null;
            parse_str(base64_decode($value), $result[$key]);
        }

        return $result;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $a
     * @param mixed $b
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function merge($a, $b) {
        if (is_object($a)) {
            if (!is_object($b)) {
                return $a;
            }
            foreach ($b as $key => $value) {
                if (isset($a->$key)) {
                    $a->$key = $this->merge($a->$key, $value);
                }
                else {
                    $a->$key = $value;
                }
            }

            return $a;
        }
        elseif (is_array($a)) {
            if (!is_array($b)) {
                return $a;
            }
            foreach ($b as $key => $value) {
                if (is_numeric($key)) {
                    $a[$key] = $value;
                }
                if (isset($a[$key])) {
                    $a[$key] = $this->merge($a[$key], $value);
                }
                else {
                    $a[$key] = $value;
                }
            }

            return $a;
        }
        else {
            return $b;
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param \Generator|array $items
     * @param $chunkSize
     * @return \Generator
     */
    public function iterateInChunks($items, $chunkSize) {
        $chunk = [];
        $count = 0;

        foreach ($items as $item) {
            $chunk[] = $item;
            $count++;

            if ($count >= $chunkSize) {
                yield $chunk;
                $chunk = [];
                $count = 0;
            }
        }

        if ($count) {
            yield $chunk;
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param array $items
     * @param string $columnName
     * @return array
     */
    public function pluck($items, $columnName) {
        return array_map(function($item) use ($columnName) {
            return $item->$columnName;
        }, $items);
    }

    /**
     * @param $items
     * @param $maxCount
     * @return \Generator|array
     */
    public function iterateNoMoreThanNTimes($items, $maxCount) {
        $count = 0;
        foreach ($items as $item) {
            yield $item;

            $count++;
            if ($count >= $maxCount) {
                break;
            }
        }

    }

    public function groupBy($columnName, $items) {
        $result = [];

        foreach ($items as $item) {
            if (!isset($result[$item->$columnName])) {
                $result[$item->$columnName] = [$item];
            }
            else {
                $result[$item->$columnName][] = $item;
            }
        }

        return $result;
    }

    public function handleHttpAndLogAllQueries($object, $proceed, $args) {
        if ($this->configuration->logAllPageQueries()) {
            $this->queryLogger->begin('page-queries');
            $this->configureHttpQueryLogging($this->queryLogger);
        }

        $result = $proceed(...$args);

        if ($result instanceof ResultInterface) {
            return $result;
        }

        if ($this->configuration->logAllPageQueries()) {
            $this->queryLogger->end('page-queries');
        }

        return $result;
    }

    public function configureHttpQueryLogging(QueryLogger $queryLogger) {
    }
}
```